# Neo4j - Create subgraph - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: neo4j

All,

I am getting an error when trying to create a subgraph using gds.beta.graph.create.subgraph

I am using Neo4j community edition version 4.2.7
gds version 1.6.4
machine memory 64G

First, I run gds.graph.create.cypher to create a graph filtered by date, returning a set of edge integer properties.

```
CALL gds.graph.create.cypher('date_20200519',
'MATCH (p)-[{data: date("2020-05-19")}]-()
RETURN DISTINCT id(p) as id',
'MATCH (p1)-[r {data: date("2020-05-19")}]->(p2)
RETURN id(p1) as source, id(p2) as target, r.atrib_resp as atrib_resp, r.conflito as conflito, r.moralidade as moralidade, r.conseq_pandemia as conseq_pandemia, r.med_contencao as med_contencao, r.met_tratamento as met_tratamento')
YIELD graphName, nodeCount, relationshipCount, createMillis;
```

graphName - "date_20200519"
nodeCount - 222.244
relationshipCount - 444.246
createMillis - 795277

This is ok. I can run a pageRank over this graph without problems. When I try to create a subgraph, filtering by one of the properties I get an error:

```
CALL gds.beta.graph.create.subgraph('date_20200519_atrib_resp_subgraph', 'date_20200519', '*', 'r.atrib_resp = 1')
YIELD graphName, fromGraphName, nodeCount, relationshipCount
```

ERROR Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
Failed to invoke procedure gds.beta.graph.create.subgraph: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 45647 out of bounds for length 3473

Please, could someone help me?

Thank you in advance, Laufer

Comment: Can you report this issue directly to github? https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science

Comment: Hi, Tomaž, I posted this issue in neo4j community 12 days ago and I've got no answers

Comment: Hi, Tomaž, I just opened an issue directly to github.